# Extract records between two dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have a set of data that contains temperature values in ten minute intervals.

I'm only interested in the temperature between 8am and 7pm.

I'm therefore trying to extract only those records (rows) and put them into sheet 2

I know excel has a its way of defining the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss as a number. For example, 43861.76111 is 31/01/2020 18:26. so I was thinking I could convert all the date/time cells to that "general" number and then write something like: (=IF "range" contains >*.33333 or <*.7916666 then extract to cell A2 on Sheet 2)

Is there a way I could write this?

Comment: This can be done with a formula, but it would be an array type formula and if the data is large the time lag on the calculation will be large.  VBA will be quicker and more reliable and less likely to user error.

Comment: I think you could use Advanced Filter here as well.